# Is there a problem if I install Steam for Linux AND Steam via PlayOnLinux?

Tags: 12.10, wine, games, steam, playonlinux

I've been enjoying playing in Ubuntu 12.10 using Steam for Linux. The thing is some games (like Borderlands2) can't be installed there because you can only install games for Linux.

Previously I used Steam (for Windows) installing it with PlayOnLinux in Ubuntu 12.10. Is there a problem if a install them both at once?

Comment: I doubt it will be an issue, Steam for Linux will be native and Steam via PlayonLinux will be emulated via Wine

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have two accounts, you can't be logged into both at once.  Otherwise, I can't see why you'd have a problem.